# Do openssl-1.0.1g has android platform support?

Tags: android, android-ndk, openssl, heartbleed-bug

Because of the heartbleed issue in some versions of OpenSSL, I need to update my OpenSSL version to openssl-1.0.1g. Does it has support for android platform? If yes, can somebody suggest me about the building procedures? I couldn't compile the source for android platform.

Any kind suggestion is highly appreciated.

Note: I will use openssl for android-ndk

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Do openssl-1.0.1g has android platform support?

Yes.

1. Go to [OpenSSL and Android](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Android) and fetch `setenv-android.sh`
2. Ensure `ANDROID_NDK_ROOT` is set
3. Ensure `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` is set
4. Open `setenv-android.sh`, and ensure `_ANDROID_NDK`, `_ANDROID_EABI` and `_ANDROID_API` suit your taste
5. Run the following commands (note the leading dot when running `setenv-android.sh`)

   `$ . ./setenv-android.sh`

   `$ cd openssl-1.0.1g/`

   `$ perl -pi -e 's/install: all install_docs install_sw/install: install_docs install_sw/g' Makefile.org`

   `$ ./config shared -no-ssl2 -no-ssl3 -no-comp -no-hw -no-engine --openssldir=/usr/local/ssl/$ANDROID_API`

   `$ make all`

   `$ sudo -E make install CC=$ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc RANLIB=$ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN/arm-linux-androideabi-ranlib`

After the install, your Android OpenSSL will be located in, for example, `/usr/local/ssl/android-18`.

---

> Any kind suggestion is highly appreciated.

**Note**: Android's Zygote is like Linux/Unix `init`. All processes inherit from it. The problem is, Zygote loads OpenSSL and its probably a down level version. So you will have to create a wrapper shared object that *statically* links to OpenSSL. Your program will call into your wrapper shared object to avoid the already-mapped-in and down level version of OpenSSL.

Comment: After ./config you have to run 'make depend' before 'make all'

source: https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Android